# Is it safe to keep server name and path to files in public git repository?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, safety

Hopefully this question is not off-topic:

I find myself constantly `scp`ing files from a remote server, and I want to keep a bash script in GitHub that invokes `scp` and brings files. Is it safe to let the world know the server and the path from which I copy files?

I know nothing about security, but is the following situation possible?

Imagine somebody modifies one of the dependencies of my project (another open source project I don't own). In a function I call from that project, a person hides something that `ssh` and removes the files in my path.

Should I simply `gitignore` my bash script, or is it safe?

Comment: You can have a private github repository, and you do not even have to put a repository on github. Git is distributed version control system, so you can have the repository no your computer only, and clone it to locations where you need it.

Comment: But in case this information got public. Is it safe?

Comment: that depends on 1. how confidential/sensitive the hostname, path, and filename(s) are and 2. whether you make the mistake of also publishing your ssh keys or password.    Also, "safe" in what sense? What do you fear might happen?  What is at risk?   Safety and security are non-binary.    BTW, if you blindly execute code you download from the internet, you will always be at risk of executing malicious or incompetently written code.